# An unexpected error occurred on a send. EOF or 0 bytes from the transport stream

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, httpwebrequest

I make a request to an https site with this code:

```
 webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri(urlDestination));
            webRequest.Method = "POST";
            webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            webRequest.ContentLength = bytes.Length;

            Stream writer = webRequest.GetRequestStream();
            writer.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            if (writer != null)
            {
                writer.Close();
            }

            response = new StreamReader(webRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
```

and get this error:

```
System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send. ---> System.IO.IOException: Received an unexpected EOF or 0 bytes from the transport stream.
   at System.Net.FixedSizeReader.ReadPacket(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ForceAuthentication(Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Net.TlsStream.CallProcessAuthentication(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(Object userData)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode code, CleanupCode backoutCode, Object userData)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Net.TlsStream.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult result)
   at System.Net.TlsStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.PooledStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeaders(Boolean async)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream(TransportContext& context)
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()
   at Nop.Proxy.send_sync_post.process(NameValueCollection parametersReceived)
   at Nop.Proxy.Includes.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
```

I after checking on the web about the error I found this solution and didn't worked:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
```

after taking to the supplier he said that he encountered this error

```
SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:1408A0C1:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_CLIENT_HELLO:no shared cipher) while SSL handshaking
```

I know that the error is from my part but don't know how to make the request to skip the error.

Answer (score 2):

The ssl3 statment did solve my issue, but I came across another suggestion that didn't apply to me but it does to you since you have a content length statement.

The suggestion is to remove that statement.

My working code follows:

```
//Create WebRequest
Uri JsonUri = new Uri(new Uri(JIRAInstanceUri), ServiceUri);
WebRequest RestWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(JsonUri);
RestWebRequest.Method = "GET";
RestWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
//Add proxy to WebRequest
ProxyServer.BypassArrayList.Add(JsonUri);
RestWebRequest.Proxy = ProxyServer;
//Setup authorization
string Base64Credentials = GetEncodedCredentials(UserName, Password);
RestWebRequest.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + Base64Credentials;
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
```